# Finding smallest subarray lengths for given multiple queries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given an array of integers `A[]`, of max length `N`, up to `10^6` and then `M` number of queries. While querying you will be given an integer `X` and you have to return minimum length of sub array whose sum is greater or equal to `X`. Problem is the number of such queries M can be up to `10^6`.

any clue to solve it efficiently within contest time.

Note: When M is very small we can solve with `O(M*N)` but when M is huge I guess there must be different approach.

Note: There is a way to solve the problem [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-length-subarray-sum-greater-given-value/) in `O(N)`, when M =~ 1.

Comment: Why do you say "there must be different approach" when M is huge?

Comment: otherwise it wont be solvable in contest time constraints, for example 5/10 sec. Is DP or pre processing can help?

Comment: You need the minimum length of the sub-array whose sum is >= to `X`. What do you need to know in order to retrieve this info?

Comment: Right now, the only possibility that I see to improve the (amortized) runtime is to use a pre-processing phase where you calculate the sum of the elements of all sub-arrays and create a map from the sum of the elements to the boundaries (or length) of the corresponding sub-array. Once this is done, you can retrieve what you need in constant time for all successive queries.

Comment: yes, i was thinking similarly but cant catch how to implement. still waiting if better solutions exist. thanks @nbro

Comment: Are there any constraints on `X`?

Comment: Just to make sure, are they positive integers?

Comment: @DAIe I don't know. Still searching

Comment: @ram yes all numbers are positive

Comment: Can you post a link to the contest problem - or at least describe which contest this is from?

Comment: I guess if there is some constraint on X, like X is not that big and array elements are all positive as stated previously, then we can calculate in advance for all X and then answer all the queries in O(M) time. Preprocessing would take O(N*X) time.